# Need help structuring my Inheritance with the use of Interfaces?

Tags: c#

So I am trying to stick to the whole "programming to an interface" methodology and wanted to structure some separate actions in my windows form app using interfaces.

Basically, I have a structure that I broke down like this

```
                                 IActions
               |----------------------------------------|
         IValidateAction                          IExecuteAction
     |----------------------|               |----------------------|
IIis6Validate          IIis7Validate    IIis6Actions           IIis7Actions
                            |                                       |
                 |--------------------|                  |---------------------|
        ValidateWebCreation                       CreateWebsite
```

I wanted to have an Execute() method on IActions that would propagate down.  I know I could do that with a base abstract class but, again wanted to follow the "Program to an interface" methodology as I liked the idea of injecting an instance of (interface) so that at anytime that object could receive a different object as long as that object inherited from the same base interface.

But I find that the contract enforced when you have a class inherit from an interface doesn't adherer to a interface that inherits from another interface.  I also read on another post "as long as InterfaceB can be interchangeable with InterfaceA".  Does this apply here?

Can I use this tree?
Am I forced to either use class inheritance or break this tree into separate tree structures?

Comment: FYI, "Programming to interface" does not mean interface as we know it in modern programming languages. An "Interface" is the public methods and properties of a class. Programming to interface typically implies a hierarchy of classes and then in the code that uses them, you program to interface rather than a specific concrete class. That is the variable you define is of the type of the base class while the instances you create cold be any one of the descendants (thus enabling polymorphism).

Comment: As regards interfaces and "contracts" you may want to take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2004/10/24/246947.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the interface inheriting from another interface:

if you have

```
interface IA
{
     void A();
}

interface IB : IA
{
    void B();
}
```

A class implementing `IB` must implement both `A` and `B`. You don't need to explicitly repeat the declaration from `IA` in `IB` since they are just declarations. `IB` will require everything from `IA` anyway.

I see no problem using your interface hierarchy.

As as side note you can create a parallel abstract class hierarchy that implements the corresponding interfaces (for some or all interfaces). This is relevant if you want to share some implementation, not just the declaration of some methods.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a fairly complicated interface structure. Are you sure each of the interfaces you're defining here is actually inherently meaningful and useful? Does it need such a degree of specificity in the lower level interfaces, and are the higher level interfaces specific enough to be useful?

I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say that an interface extending another interface doesn't incur the same "contract enforcement" as a class. Remember that an interface doesn't implement anything, and so in deriving one interface from another, you're merely extending the contract that must be implemented by implementing classes. The members of the parent interface are implicitly included in the contract specified by the child interface. For example:

```
interface A
{
    void Foo();
}

interface B
{
    void Bar();
}

class C : B
{
    void Foo();
    void Bar();
}
```

Class `C` must implement both `Foo` and `Bar`, since `B` "inherits" `Foo` from `A`.

You may also like to look into explicit interface implementation; see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4taxa8t2%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).

**Update**: If a method takes different parameters in more specific implementations, then you probably need to rethink your interface structure. Take a step back and think about what `IAction` represents and how client code might use it.

For example, suppose `IAction` defines a general `Execute()` method with no parameters, while more specific derivatives of `IAction` define more specific `Execute(...)` methods with parameters.

What use, then is the "general" `Execute()` method? Since each of the specific implementations actually requires additional information in the form of the parameters of the method, what exactly should the parameterless `Execute()` do?

Comment: Maybe it is over complicated.  I am just new to programming/C# so thats why I was turning here for some feedback.  Should I reduce it down to maybe

Comment: IIs6WebsiteValidation : IIisValidation

Comment: Can you only implement different variations of a method through the use over abstract classes and/or virtual methods?  So as I foresee a Execute method at the top of the hierarchy, but down at the class level or base class it might take different parameters.